# overlap button with another view

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a screen where I input some values in the input field and get search results displayed accordingly (within the `<View style={styles.dropdown}>`). I want that the list should overlap my ActionButton. Just like it overlaps my other input field.

I have already added zIndex and it works for the second input field but not for the button.

```
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeAreaViewContainer}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.searchFieldContainer}>
          <AddressSearchInput
            addressType="favouritePoint"
            iconName="search"
            textChangeHandler={textChangeHandler}/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.dropdown}>
          <LocationsFound
            addressesFound={locations.addressesFoundList}/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.fieldDescription}>
          <Text>Standortname:</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.searchFieldContainer}>
          <Item style={styles.searchField}>
            <Input style={styles.searchText}/>
          </Item>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <ActionButton buttonText="Platz Speichern"/>
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  searchFieldContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: moderateScale(120),
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    zIndex: 1,
  },

  fieldDescription: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  dropdown: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: moderateScale(215),
    zIndex: moderateScale(10),
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  container: {
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    width: '100%',
    flex:1,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add styles to your `<View style={styles.container}>`. Like:

```
container: {
  display:"flex",
  flex-direction:"column",
  //etc
}
```

Because now your `View`s are all separate from each other.

Comment: I already have styles in the container, forgot to copy it

Comment: still add `display:"flex"`